# Explained variance in TruncatedSVD

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, svd, lsa

as I tried to get my head around LSA, I discovered that I am not able to reproduce the result from TruncatedSVD using SVD. Why does this not work.

Thank you for your help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

# Iris data
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data', header=None, sep=',')
df.columns=['sepal_len', 'sepal_wid', 'petal_len', 'petal_wid', 'class']
df.dropna(how="all", inplace=True)
X = df.ix[:,0:4].values

# TruncatedSVD
lsa = TruncatedSVD(n_components=3)
X_proj = lsa.fit_transform(X)
#print(lsa.singular_values_)                  <------- error
print('Components:\n', lsa.components_)
print('Explained variance:\n', lsa.explained_variance_, '\n')

# SVD
u, s, vt = np.linalg.svd(X)
print('Components:\n', vt)
exp_var = (s**2) / (X.shape[0]-1)
print('Explained variance:\n', exp_var)
```

Comment: It seems that `TruncatedSVD` computes the variance explained in each column of the `X_proj` not the variance explained in the singular matrix. See how to compute variance on this page: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171539/percentage-of-variation-in-each-column-explained-by-each-svd-mode. And here is how `TruncatedSVD` computes variance https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a7e17117bb15eb3f51ebccc1bd53e42fcb4e6cd8/sklearn/decomposition/truncated_svd.py#L183-L192